# Vim move cursor one character in insert mode without arrow keys

Tags: vim

This might seem a little too overboard, but I switched to vim and I so happy about the workflow now. I try to discipline myself not to use the arrow keys, as keeping the hands on the alfa-keys all the time is such a big thing when writing. So when I need to navigate I get out of insert mode, move in normal mode and get back in insert mode.

There is an exception where this is actually more disrupting: I use `clang complete` with snippets and `super tab` which is great. Except every time I get a function auto completed after I fill in the parameters I am left with the cursor before `)` so to continue I have to move the cursor one character to the right. As you can imagine this happens **very often**.

The only options I have (as far as I know) are : <kbd>Esc</kbd><kbd>l</kbd><kbd>a</kbd> or <kbd>→</kbd>, and I am not happy about neither of them. The first one makes me hit 3 keys for just a simple 1 character cursor move, the second one makes me move my hand to the arrow keys. A third option would be to map <kbd>CTRL-L</kbd> or smth to <kbd>→</kbd>.

So what is the best way of doing this?

---

```
//snippets (clang complete + supertab):
foo($`param1`, $`param2`)

//after completion:
foo(var1, var2|)
              ^ ^
              | |
     I am here  |
                 Need to be here
```

`|` denotes cursor position

Comment: With similar problem, I ended up hacking on completion script in order to make it just not echo closing `)` if there is at least one argument in the function. So I type it by hand. Much more useful now.

Comment: What happens when you type `)` I bet it skips over with out actually inserting. (I don't use this plugin)

Comment: @FDinoff no, it just inserts another `)`

Comment: @bolov thats disappointing. You might be able to extract the code which does that from [auto-pairs](https://github.com/jiangmiao/auto-pairs). I have no idea if the plugins will conflict they might. The other option is to use `<C-O>l` to exit to normal mode for 1 normal mode command.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Map <kbd>)</kbd> to skip over the exisiting `)` if it is a closing parenthesis

```
inoremap <expr> )  strpart(getline('.'), col('.')-1, 1) == ")" ? "\<Right>" : ")"
```

Taken from: http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Automatically_append_closing_characters

---

**Old Answer**

`:h i_CTRL-O` execute one command, return to Insert mode.

<kbd>Ctrl-o</kbd><kbd>l</kbd> will move you one character to the right then return you to insert mode.

Alternatively some of the bracket plugins allow you to just type the closing bracket <kbd>)</kbd> and they will override the existing one.

Comment: this doesn’t work if `)` is the last character on the line (and this happens often as you write code). `CTRL-O a` however does work. So I guess we saved one key. :)

Comment: True `del` `)` is only two characters and will always put you after the closing parenthesis.

Comment: skipping over the ')' works like a charm, thank you

Answer (score 1):

Type the following to find the control keys that are used in insert mode.

```
:help insert-index
```

ctrl-b is not used, but you may want to sacrifice some other key.

```
imap <c-b> <right>
```

This works to move the cursor right one char.
Or map some double char.

```
imap jj <right>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `ctrl-f` to move one character to the right, in insert mode.

This works on my mac in general. There are other such commands using `ctrl`, but they might not always work. Eg `ctrl-b` brings you back one character in my vim insert mode and on my Mac, except when I am editing something inside a stackoverflow answer, in which case it is mapped to making text bold :)

Answer (score 0):

Seems to be `ctrl-f` can skip a character. Try that first,

or

You can type the character one more time for auto completion.

```
foo(var1, var2|)
              ^ ^
              | |
     I am here  |
                 Need to be here
```

In your chart, just type `)`, this will make you confirm the last character and then move on. I understand this is not exactly what's asked for, but so far i can see this is very easy and bullet proof.

Answer (score 0):

if you are using karabiner elements, it's very easily by next config.

```
                    {
                        "description": "CRTL+j -> down_arrow",
                        "manipulators": [
                            {
                                "from": {
                                    "key_code": "j",
                                    "modifiers": {
                                        "mandatory": [
                                            "left_control"
                                        ]
                                    }
                                },
                                "to": [
                                    {
                                        "key_code": "down_arrow"
                                    }
                                ],
                                "type": "basic"
                            }
                        ]
                    },
                    {
                        "description": "CRTL+k -> up_arrow",
                        "manipulators": [
                            {
                                "from": {
                                    "key_code": "k",
                                    "modifiers": {
                                        "mandatory": [
                                            "left_control"
                                        ]
                                    }
                                },
                                "to": [
                                    {
                                        "key_code": "up_arrow"
                                    }
                                ],
                                "type": "basic"
                            }
                        ]
                    },
                    {
                        "description": "CRTL+h -> left_arrow",
                        "manipulators": [
                            {
                                "from": {
                                    "key_code": "h",
                                    "modifiers": {
                                        "mandatory": [
                                            "left_control"
                                        ]
                                    }
                                },
                                "to": [
                                    {
                                        "key_code": "left_arrow"
                                    }
                                ],
                                "type": "basic"
                            }
                        ]
                    },
                    {
                        "description": "CRTL+l -> right_arrow",
                        "manipulators": [
                            {
                                "from": {
                                    "key_code": "l",
                                    "modifiers": {
                                        "mandatory": [
                                            "left_control"
                                        ]
                                    }
                                },
                                "to": [
                                    {
                                        "key_code": "right_arrow"
                                    }
                                ],
                                "type": "basic"
                            }
                        ]
                    },
```

For me it's working the best, no matter where I'm using vim, in vscodevim, ideavim etc or terminal vim.
Yes not ideal, but working perfectly, especially in case vim emulators